# Long running job should not prevent a MR from being merged

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Consider a pipeline with the following jobs:

- `build`: Runs the build and takes 1 minute
- `report`: Runs a static code analysis, posts the result to the MR and takes 59 minutes

Developers should be informed about the results of the `report` stage as soon as possible, but it should not block the MR from being merged. The pipeline should behave like this:

1. `build` must always be successful, before the MR can be merged.
2. `report` should always be started eventually and executed successfully, but it should not be mandatory to wait for it in order to be able to merge the MR.

Is there a possibility in gitlab to create such a pipeline?

So far, I am aware of the following options:

1. Disable the "*[Pipelines must succeed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html#only-allow-merge-requests-to-be-merged-if-the-pipeline-succeeds)*" setting: In this case, the MR can be merged, even if `build` is not successful.
2. Set `allow_failure` for `report` to true. In this case, The MR can be merged after `build` has completed by cancelling the `report` job, but this violates the requirement that the report should always be executed. Also it is poor developer experience if you have to cancel an optional job before being able to merge.
3. Execute the `report` job after merge. This has two drawbacks:

   - I will get the report only when the MR is merged instead of as soon as possible.
   - The `report` job cannot post it's result to the MR, which would notify the involved persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your `report` job into a child pipeline (= a separate `.yml` file in your project) and trigger it with the [`trigger` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#examples) and **without** [`strategy: depend`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerstrategy).
This allows you to trigger the job without waiting for it and without considering its state in your pipeline.